# Como puxar as informações do banco de dados de maneira organizada

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um projeto Web utilizando PHP e MySql.

E cheguei em uma parte desse projeto, em que preciso buscar as informações que foram cadastradas no BD.

Por exemplo: Eu cadastrei um titular e 2 dependentes (3 pessoas). Os dependentes estão vinculados ao Titular através de um ID (ID - Chave Primária do Titular / TITULAR - Chave estrangeira do Dependente). O que eu preciso é buscar todos os dependentes que estão vinculados ao titular por esse ID e logo em seguida, exibir eles juntamente com o Titular em questão.

Sou um completo iniciante em PHP e MySql, então me perdoem erros grotescos. (O código ainda não foi refatorado.)

Aqui está o select que eu utilizei para tentar fazer isso:

```html
include_once('dbcon.php');
  $id = $_SESSION['id']; 
  $consult = "SELECT * FROM dependentes FULL OUTER JOIN dental ON dependentes.titular = dental.id";
  $result_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $consult);
```

E aqui é onde eu exibo o resultado:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 centro">
          <?php
            while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sql)){
          ?>
            <div class="col-sm-12 dados">
              <h3><?php echo $data["tipo_user"]; ?></h3>
              <h5>Nome: <?php echo $data["nome"]; ?></h5>
              <h5>CPF: <?php echo $data["cpf"]; ?></h5>
            </div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Até aqui ok, o problema é que ao exibir os dados ele puxa todos os dados da tabela dependentes, ou se eu inverter:

```html
$consult = "SELECT * FROM dental FULL OUTER JOIN dependentes ON  dental.id = dependentes.titular";
  $result_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $consult);
```

Ele puxa todos os dados da tabela dental (Titulares).

Eu queria fazer um mix dos dois, por exemplo: 
Cadastrei um Titular (Chave Primária(AI) ID: 55).
E depois cadastrei 3 dependentes nele e cada um recebeu a chave estrangeira (Titular: 55) que faz a ligação entre eles.

Agora quero exibir o titular e os dependentes que são referentes à ele.

Desde já agradeço o tempo dedicado à cada resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi a dificuldade esta na consulta ao banco de dados e não na impressão dos registros usando o PHP. De qualquer forma acredito que você esteja procurando o CROSS JOIN...

```
SELECT * FROM dental CROSS JOIN dependentes ON dental.id = dependentes.titular;
```

Ou você pode fazer assim também

```
SELECT * FROM dental, dependentes WHERE dental.id = dependentes.titular;
```

A consulta vai retornar 1 registro para cada dependente, os dados do titular estarão nas colunas. Ai é só organizar e mostrar os resultados da melhor forma para o seu sistema.